# How to use nested $expand on CDS Views with OData.publish:true

Tags: odata, sap-gateway, cds

Imagine we have three nested CDS Views `A>B>C` that are linked together with associations with `0..*` from top to bottom (e.g.: A > 0..* > B > 0..* > C). All three CDS Views are published with `@OData.publish:true` and their corresponding service is activated in /n/IWFND/MAINT_SERVICE.

Now I want in one call to get one entry from A with all it's corresponding entries in B and ALL their corresponding entries in C.

[SAP Documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/50c996852b32456c96d3161a95544cdb/d990bd1fbc98479d97078aa3890f5bb3.html?locale=en-US&q=%24expand#retrieve-an-integration-object-with-expanded-or-nested-navigation-properties) states that `$expand` functions exactly this way, but when I call `/sap/opu/odata/sap/<service_name>/a(1)?$expand=tob,tob/toc&$format=json` I only get "Resource for segment 'toc' not found".

I've found many Tutorials on how to do this by defining the structure of the OData Service manually in SEGW ([Example 1](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/11/24/multi-level-expansion-with-getexpandedentityset/), [Example 2](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/11/18/expand-parent-child-entities-in-a-single-expansion-getexpandedentityset/)) but none that use CDS Views with `@OData.publish:true`.

I also tried alternating the syntax of my call to various things, like `/sap/opu/odata/sap/<service_name>/a(1)?$expand=tob($expand=toc)&$format=json` or `/sap/opu/odata/sap/<service_name>/a(1)/tob?$expand=toc&$format=json` but it didn't work either. [ODatav2 Documentation](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) also states that my first syntax is the correct one.

A short MVP:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZFDIIA'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'basic view for zfdi_a'
@VDM.viewType: #BASIC
@OData.publish: true
define view zfdi_i_a
  as select distinct from zfdi_a
  association [0..*] to zfdi_i_b as _b on $projection.AId = _b.AId
{
  key a_id        as AId,
      description as Description,

      _b as b
}

@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZFDIIB'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'basic view for zfdi_b'
@VDM.viewType: #BASIC
@OData.publish: true
define view zfdi_i_b
  as select distinct from zfdi_b
  association [1..1] to zfdi_i_a as _a on $projection.AId = _a.AId
  association [0..*] to zfdi_i_c as _c on $projection.BId = _c.BId
{
  key b_id        as BId,
      description as Description,
      a_id        as AId,

      _a          as a,
      _c          as c
}

@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZFDIIC'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'basic view for zfdi_c'
@VDM.viewType: #BASIC
@OData.publish: true
define view zfdi_i_c
  as select distinct from zfdi_c
  association [1..1] to zfdi_i_b as _b on $projection.BId = _b.BId
{
  key c_id        as CId,
      description as Description,
      b_id        as BId,

      _b          as b
}
```

Is a nested `$expand` not possible with automatically published CDS Views via OData and must I implement this manually or am I missing something here?